# How do I get my disks to spin down after one hour?

Tags: hard-drive, debian, power-management

I'm currently configuring a new home server, and I am trying to get the disks to spin down after one hour. But they do not spin down.

## Setup

I have my entire system on an ssd: /dev/sda. I have three hdds in the system: /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc and /dev/sdd. They are not mounted, although they do contain (active) LVM volumes.

## What does work

I can put the disk into standby using :

```
hdparm -y /dev/sdb
```

The disk stays spun down for days (if I leave the system alone), indicating (I think) that the system really isn't generating any activity

Using relatively small values for the timeout like :

```
hdparm -S 180 /dev/sdb
hdparm -S 240 /dev/sdc
hdparm -S 241 /dev/sdd
```

also works. Each of the disks spins down after the specified amount of time (15 minutes, 20 minutes and 30 minutes, respectively)

## What doesn't work

I try to set the timeout value to one hour, like so :

```
hdparm -S 242 /dev/sdb
```

The command appears to succeed, but the disk doesn't go into standby at all (i.e. after a day, the disk is still in active/idle mode, as witnessed by my power meter, as well as

```
hdparm -C /dev/sdb
```

## System details

This is Debian Squeeze, running on an Atom-powered Asus motherboard (AT5NM10T-I). The disks are:

```
[1.948217] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA OCZ VERTEX PLUS  3.50 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[1.953713] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA ST2000DL003-9VT1 CC3C PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[1.954302] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA ST31500341AS     SD1B PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[1.954873] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access ATA ST31500341AS     SD1B PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

Comment: @syneticon-dj: Be careful with this suggestion, some people tend to create new questions on the suggested site(s) instead of waiting for their question to get migrated by votes. Kees-Jan: Please don't do that :)

Comment: Just want to add, shouldn't it be hdparm -S 720 /dev/sdb for one hour standby?

Comment: @ColdT: Nope, it shouldn't be. According to the hdparm manual "The encoding of the timeout value is somewhat peculiar". See the manual for the full explanation (http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its default configuration, smartd checks disk status once every 30 minutes, except when the disk is in standby.

Apparently, that generates enough disk-activity for disks to never actually go to sleep (for timeouts larger than 30 minutes), but doesn't wake-up any sleeping disks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try if it works when all partitions on that disc ar unmounted. I also fiddled with this a while ago and i had some troubles with regular reads/writes holding the disc in spinning state.

On the other hand see this:

> **Power cycling control**
>   Shutting down and rebooting a computer or resuming it from hibernation cycles the power to the drives in the computer. The spin-up operation performed by a drive after a power cycle is believed to place more stress on the drive than running the drive continuously for a long period of time.
>
> Based on professional experience of system administrators, it is believed that there is a direct relationship between the number of power cycles of a computer and the probability of failure of its drives. In other words, a computer with a high uptime may have a lower probability of drive failure than one that has its power cycled routinely.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Minimizing_Hard_Disk_Drive_Failure_and_Data_Loss/Stress_Control

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my test setup, the disks are not mounted (as mentioned in the _setup_ section). I am aware that people believe that powercycling the disk causes stress, but we're talking here about a disk that is rarely used (less than once a month), and I do have a power bill to pay.