# Ways to shutdown internal drives completely?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

Are there really no ways to completely shut down a hard drive in Windows without pulling out the power cable? Sometimes having too many drives and not enough money to buy a NAS can be a little bit too loud.

There has to be a way at least?

Comment: You can set the hard drives to automatically turn off after a period of no usage, but I don't think it applies individually. The setting is under Power in Control Panel.

Comment: Individual drives can have a power down setting that can be set via manufacturer-provided utilities or something like *hdparm* on Linux.

Comment: The OP of [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/910076/ways-to-shut-down-sleep-and-wake-up-hard-drives-on-command) has the answer in his question.

Answer (score 0):

MS has [directions to dismount a HD](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mount-dismount-drive#1TC=windows-7) (windows 7, but also applies to Windows 8): launch the *Computer Management* CPL applet; on the left, select *Storage* and *Disk Management*; right-click the drive to remove and select *Change Drive Letter and Paths*; finally select *Remove*.

*Caveat*: Though this will *dismount* the drive, it depends on the HD firmware to spin down, and it might not. If this drive is going to be mounted and dismounted on a regular basis, it might be more efficient to remove the drive and put it in an external USB enclosure. You can *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* easily, and you can unplug it if it is not to be used for a while.

Comment: not sure that was the link you wanted, as that looks more like mapping (and unmapping) a drive, not "unmouting" from the os seeing it?

Comment: It includes "Remove" drive.